# Checking if a program is running

Tags: ruby, process

Is there a way to find out if a program is running on your desktop through a Ruby program? Would it be as simple as using a system call?

Example:

```
def find_process
  process = 'Windows'
  if process != #some system call to check the process
    #execute process
  else
    puts "Process not found"
  end
end
```

It's probably worth mentioning that I am running OS Windows 7.

Comment: Is the program running as a Windows service?

Comment: @orde just any type of program, like Microsoft Word for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a contrived example that uses [`tasklist`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tasklist.mspx?mfr=true).  It assigns the result of the backtick system call to a `status` variable.  If this variable is empty, then the specified program isn't running.

```
def find_process
  status = `tasklist | find "notepad.exe"`
  if status.empty?
    puts "Process is not running"
  else
    puts "Process is running"
  end
end

find_process
```

Comment: So it is as simple as running a system call.. Thank you.